# Getting menu item to animate

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to animate a menu item, while the activity is loading, in my ActionBar (actually ActionBarSherlock).  The code I have works the first time the activity is created, but any time the activity is called again, I get a NullReference exception on "loadingItem" because `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called after `onCreate`.  I tried using `onPrepareOptionsMenu` but the same thing.

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockActivity  {
    private MenuItem loadingItem;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle) 
    {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final ImageView ivRefresh = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.refresh_view, null);

        final Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.refresh);
        ivRefresh.startAnimation(rotation);
        loadingItem.setActionView(ivRefresh);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        loadingItem = menu.findItem(R.id.loading);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

my_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/loading" 
          android:icon="@drawable/loading"
          android:showAsAction="always"          
    />

</menu>
```

Update:

This ultimately what I'm trying to accomplish.  I have a WebView and I want to show a loading icon until the WebView has finished loading:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle) 
    {
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);  
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebBrowserClient());

        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final ImageView ivRefresh = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.refresh_view, null);

        final Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.refresh);
        ivRefresh.startAnimation(rotation);
        loadingItem.setActionView(ivRefresh);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

                if (!isFinishing() && progress == 100 && loadingItem != null && loadingItem.getActionView() != null)
                {
                    loadingItem.getActionView().clearAnimation();
                    loadingItem.setActionView(null);
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: When do you want the animation to run? Always? On certain events? On create?

Comment: I added more code to my OP which should clear up what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreateOptionsMenu` will always be called after `onCreate`.  In fact, `onCreate` will [always](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) be the first method called when an activity is created.

You should either assign the `loadingItem` variable before you use it, or declare it as static so that the reference isn't deleted when the activity is destroyed (which still may happen, in which case I recommend the first option).

Why not set the animation in `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

Comment: I researched but couldn't figure out how to assign loadingItem to a menu item outside of onCreateOptionsMenu and onPrepareOptionsMenu.  Also, when I breakpoint my code onCreateOptionsMenu is called before onCreate the first time the activity is created, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @Kris, why not start the animation in `onCreateOptionsMenu`?  You won't need it to be running until it is inflated anyway.

Comment: Ugh, sorry I'm confusing myself.  onCreate is being called before onCreateOptionsMenu.  Only on the initial activity creation is it not.  I don't think adding the animation to onCreateOptionsMenu will help, if onCreate is called first.

Comment: @KrisB if you put the animation start code in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, it will always start when the user clicks the menu button.  Could you do that, and combine it with a class-global flag in case the web view has already been loaded?  That way you'll only start the animation if the user brings up the menu item.

Comment: Actually, I just tried adding it to onCreateOptionsMenu and that worked, so I guess you were right.  BTW, how do you add that gray background to certain words?

Comment: If you add uptick single quotes around the word, it will change it to monospace with the gray background.  It's the key to the left of the '1' key on the keyboard, not the one next to the enter key.  Glad you got it working!