# setActionView on menuItem, makes the menuItem not clickable

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, android-toolbar

In referring to [Getting menu item to animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133745/getting-menu-item-to-animate), I manage to make my MenuItem animate as desired. It is using setActionView(myAnimateView).

However, during animation (or before I setActionView(null) to clear the action view, the MenuItem is not responding to click i.e. onOptionsItemSelected(...) is not called.

How could I resolve this? Found potential related article https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/131. Is this a limitation of setActionView or expected behaviour?

I could workaround this by setting my adding a clickListener to myAnimateView object. But it seems weird to need to do that, since it is attached to menuItem.

Hopes to hear from someone... Thanks!!

Note: setActionView(null) after the animation, resume everything back to normal, and the menuItem is now clickable.